# Ember.js: Loading a set of objects related to this object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

(Using Ember-Data and the RESTAdapter/RESTSerializer)

Say I have two models, `Post` and `Comments`, where `Post` has `Comments`.  I would like to be able to do a `find` on Post, and have it automatically fetch the comments that belongs to it.  However, my API does *not* return the comments along with the Post, it will only return the Post data (in this example, just 'name'... so `comments` is not in the JSON returned by the server).

This is what I am doing:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true, inverse: 'post' })
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post', { async: true })
});
```

When I output the comments array into a template, it returns `<DS.PromiseArray:ember###>`, and if I console.log it, it returns what looks like a promise object.  However, looking at the Network tab in the Chrome dev tools, no API call was made to fetch the `comment`s that are associated with the `Post`.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is a sample JSBin that shows the problem I am having:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yocunalo/5/edit

As you can see, the API call to fetch the comments is never happening.  When I try to display the array, it gives me a Promise object string, and when I try to iterate over it, no values are ever there.  Looking at the console log, there is never any attempted GET to the `comment` endpoint at all.

Comment: Have you attempted to use a non async relationship yet? Also can you post some code that shows how you are retrieving your Post model.  A jsfiddle would be excellent as well.

One option that you have, which I have used before is to do something called sideloading.  I'm going to assume here that the relationship is not an embedded one.  But when you make your call to the post, it will return from the server your `post: {}` object.  If you also send back an object at the same level in the JSON as the post object, and array of comments, they will be loaded into the store as well.

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post with a JSBin example.  I tried {async: false}, but it still never performs a GET on the secondary resource.  I have tried in the past to do the manual sideloading, but it became overly-complicated and I was advised that ember could (and should) take care of it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to load resources separately, but in Ember it is hard to make it work. Now I'm using sideloading, like this: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/386/edit

You can read more about sideloading relationships here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships